# how to get a users roles discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to check if a user has a role but when I try to get the user it always returns the bot user, not the wanted user. How can I go about fixing this?

Here's my code:

```js
const member = client.guilds.cache.get(localVars.ServerID).members.cache.find((member) => {
    console.log(member.username);
    return member.username == localVars.username;
});
const role = client.guilds.cache.get(localVars.ServerID).roles.cache.find((role) => {
    return role.name === localVars.RoleName;
});
console.log(member);
if (member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
    localVars.ReturnValue = 1;
} else {
    localVars.ReturnValue = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little bit overcomplicated and some things are just unneccessary / wrong, e.g. that you call `return` in the `find()` and `get()` functions :D

You could simplify it like this:

```js
const { guilds } = client;
const targetGuild = guilds.cache.get(localVars.ServerID);

const member = targetGuild.members.cache.find(user => user.username === localVars.username);

const role = targetGuild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === localVars.RoleName);

if(member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
   localVars.ReturnValue = 1
} else {
   localVars.ReturnValue = 0
}
```

Comment: nope it still returns the bots member not users

Comment: Do a `console.log(localVars.username)` right under the first line and check if this returns the bot's username

Comment: its telling me that members is undefined now

Comment: Whats the value of `localVars.username`??